# Is there a way to retrieve the access public key of a certificate stored in Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Is there a way to retrieve the access public key of a certificate stored in Azure Key Vault?

Want to retrieve the public key of the certificate

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`KeyVaultClient.GetCertificateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclientextensions.getcertificateasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_KeyVaultClientExtensions_GetCertificateAsync_Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_IKeyVaultClient_System_String_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

This method returns a `CertificateBundle`.  You can get the CER contents from [`CertificateBund.Cer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.models.certificatebundle.cer?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_Models_CertificateBundle_Cer)